# Owl carousel 2 urlhash slide speed 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I fixed it myself by setting:

`navSpeed:800, smartSpeed:'0',dragEndSpeed:800`

I'm using `owl carousel 2` with url hash nav.

Is there a way to set slide speed to `0`? I want to be able to link from different sitepages without sliding to the correct carousel `#item`.

Comment: Please be careful in using the tag descriptions.  This is not about the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]), but about the OWL carousel ([tag:owl-carousel]).  Better tagging helps to get the people who know about the topic to see it.